# Python Printing Incredibly Slowly

Tags: r, python-3.x, numpy, io, rpy2

I'm running into a problem I've never encountered before, and it's frustrating the hell out of me. I'm using `rpy2` to interface with `R` from within a python script and normalize an array. For some reason, when I go to piece my output together and print to a file, it takes **ages** to print. It also slows down as it proceeds until it's dripping maybe a few kb of data to output per minute.

My input file is large (366 MB), but this is running on a high performance computing cluster with near *unlimited* resources. It should have no problem slamming through this.

Here's where I'm actually doing the normalization:

```
matrix = sample_list  # two-dimensional array
v = robjects.FloatVector([ element for col in matrix for element in col ])
m = robjects.r['matrix'](v, ncol = len(matrix), byrow=False)
print("Performing quantile normalization.")
Rnormalized_matrix = preprocessCore.normalize_quantiles(m)
normalized_matrix = np.array(Rnormalized_matrix)
```

As you can see, I end up with a `numpy.array` object containing my now-normalized data. I have another list containing other strings I want to print to the output as well, each element corresponding to an element of the numpy array. So I iterate through, joining each row of the array into a string and print both to output.

```
for thing in pos_list:  # List of strings corresponding with each row of array.
    thing_index = pos_list.index(thing)

    norm_data = normalized_matrix[thing_index]
    out_data = "\t".join("{0:.2f}".format(piece) for piece in norm_data)

    print(thing + "\t" + out_data, file=output)
```

I'm no pro, but I have no idea why things are slowing down so much. Any insight or suggestions would be very, very appreciated. I can post more/the rest of the script if anyone thinks it may be helpful.

**Update:**
Thanks to @lgautier for his profiling suggestion. Using the `line_profiler` module, I was able to pinpoint my issue to the line:
`thing_index = pos_list.index(thing)`

This makes sense since this list is very long, and it also explains the slow down as the script proceeds. Simply using a count instead fixed the issue.

Profiling of original code (notice the % for the specified line):

```
   Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
   115         1     16445761 16445761.0     15.5       header, pos_list, normalized_matrix = Quantile_Normalize(in
   117         1           54     54.0      0.0         print("Creating output file...")
   120         1         1450   1450.0      0.0         output = open(output_file, "w")
   122         1            8      8.0      0.0         print(header, file=output)
   124                                                  # Iterate through each position and print QN'd data
   125    100000        74600      0.7      0.1         for thing in pos_list:
   126     99999     85244758    852.5     80.3                 thing_index = pos_list.index(thing)
   129     99999       158741      1.6      0.1                 norm_data = normalized_matrix[thing_index]
   130     99999      3801631     38.0      3.6                 out_data = "\t".join("{0:.2f}".format(piece) for pi
   132     99999       384248      3.8      0.4                 print(thing + "\t" + out_data, file=output)
   134         1         3641   3641.0      0.0         output.close()
```

Profiling new code:

```
   Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
   115         1     16177130 16177130.0     82.5       header, pos_list, normalized_matrix = Quantile_Normalize(input_file, data_start)
   116
   117         1           55     55.0      0.0         print("Creating output file...")
   118
   119
   120         1        26157  26157.0      0.1         output = open(output_file, "w")
   121
   122         1           11     11.0      0.0         print(header, file=output)
   123
   124                                                  # Iterate through each position and print QN'd data
   125         1            1      1.0      0.0         count = 0
   126    100000        62709      0.6      0.3         for thing in pos_list:
   127     99999        58587      0.6      0.3                 thing_index = count
   128     99999        67164      0.7      0.3                 count += 1
   131     99999        85664      0.9      0.4                 norm_data = normalized_matrix[thing_index]
   132     99999      2877634     28.8     14.7                 out_data = "\t".join("{0:.2f}".format(piece) for piece in norm_data)
   134     99999       240654      2.4      1.2                 print(thing + "\t" + out_data, file=output)
   136         1         1713   1713.0      0.0         output.close()
```

Comment: Does pos_list contain R objects? I don't use rpy2 frequently, but from my experience, the interactions between the two languages is fairly slow.

Comment: What part is actually slow?  Try commenting out bits and pieces to see what makes it faster.  I would expect `[ element for col in matrix for element in col ]`  is quite slow.

Comment: No, `pos_list` just contains strings. The `[ element for col in matrix for element in col ]` bit is slow, but it's before any actual output to file, so it's not the bottleneck here.

Comment: Interesting you use *incredibly slow*, *slowing down*, and even bold *ages* but do not mention in real terms how long it takes. Is it 5 mins or 50 mins? Does same operation run *slow* in full version of R?

Comment: I will not lie, I am a complete scrub when it comes to R and was having trouble getting labels to conserve their formatting when outputting to a file. I end up running it through another python script to fix all the wonky formatting issues, so I figured I could kill two birds with one stone. `write.table` from R is also quite slow, but nothing compared to this. Anyway, the above slows to ouputting 5-10 kb *a minute*, at which point I usually kill the script because I can't really wait a month for it to finish. I will profile the code in a few hours once I have a few minutes free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly everything is running fine and with good performance up to (and including) the line:

```
normalized_matrix = np.array(Rnormalized_matrix)
```

At that line the resulting matrix is turned into a numpy array (literally - it can be even faster when avoiding to copy the data, as in http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/numpy.html?from-rpy2-to-numpy ).

I cannot see the performance issues in the rest of the script related to rpy2.

Now what might be happening is that this is not because it says "HPC" on the label that it is high-performance in any and every situation with all code. Did you consider running that slow last loop through a code profiler ? It would tell you where the time is spent.

Comment: So using the `line_profiler` module, I was able to pinpoint that ~80% of the time is being spent on this line: `thing_index = pos_list.index(thing)`, which I guess should have been obvious since the file is millions of lines long and as it slows down as it has to search further and further as it proceeds. I replaced it by just using a count and saw a massive speed-up. An enormous oversight on my part, but as your answer led me to the right strategy, I'm marking it as the answer. I will update my question to reflect the profiling and changes.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, I usually use a generator to avoid the temporary list of many tiny strings.

```
out_data = "\t".join("{0:.2f}".format(piece) for piece in norm_data)
```

But it's hard to tell if this part was the slow one.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good tip. I've updated my code above with it, though it did not solve the issue.